# MediaPlayer and Slider using Foreground Service

Tags: android, service, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer, foreground-service

I have a mediaplayer inside a foreground service and I'm trying to update my Slider but I'm not seeing a way to do that. I tried creating a static variable but the issue is I'm not able to find a way to keep the slider updated. It can update on pause and start but never in real time.

```
Foreground Service

package com.mypackage.jackdaw.core.service

import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioAttributes
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.mypackage.jackdaw.R

class MusicService : Service(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {

    private var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
    private var title: String = ""
    private var artist: String = ""

    companion object {
        var time: Int = 0
    }


    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        when (intent?.action) {
            Actions.START.toString() -> start(intent = intent, id = intent.extras?.getString(EXTRAS.ID.toString())!!)
            Actions.STOP.toString() -> stop()
            Actions.RESUME.toString() -> resume()
            Actions.STOP_PLAYER.toString() -> stopPlayer()
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun start(intent: Intent?, id: String) {
        title = intent!!.getStringExtra(EXTRAS.TITLE.toString()).toString()
        artist = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS.ARTIST.toString()).toString()
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "music_channel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(artist)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)



        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer().apply {
            setOnPreparedListener(this@MusicService)
            setDataSource("myURL")

            prepareAsync()
            time = mMediaPlayer?.currentPosition ?: 0
        }
    }

    private fun resume() {
        mMediaPlayer?.start()
    }

    private fun stop() {
        mMediaPlayer?.pause()
        Log.d("MusicService", mMediaPlayer?.currentPosition.toString())
        time = mMediaPlayer?.currentPosition ?: 0
    }

    private fun stopPlayer() {
        mMediaPlayer?.stop()
    }

    enum class Actions {
        START, STOP, RESUME, STOP_PLAYER
    }

    enum class EXTRAS {
        ID, TITLE, ARTIST
    }

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp?.start()
    }
    
}
```

and the Composable

```
 Slider(
                value = 0f,
                onValueChange = {  },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 32.dp, end = 32.dp, top = 16.dp)
)
```

Thanks, I just can't seem to find a way to have it be updated in real time.

I tried using a static variable, and tried seeing if I could use a remember mutablestateof could continuously call a function.

Comment: If you're trying to update UI from foreground service then you can either bind the service to Activity and get the updates via ServiceConnection or use LocalBroadcastManager to update. There can be multiple ways to implement this as well